# ¿Cómo hacer a un bloque de código una función, en python?

Tags: python, funciones

soy novato en programación. He realizado un bloque de códigos, pero ahora tengo que hacer ese bloque de códigos sea una función y que me arroje el mismo resultado. Espero haber sido claro. Cómo lograría aquello.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recuerda que siempre es recomendable poner el código en forma de texto, para que nosotros lo podamos copiar fácilmente y hacer pruebas con el. Si pones una imagen quien conteste tiene que copiar manualmente las cosas, lo cual hará que a muchos les den menos ganas de contestar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que tu código ya funciona, que la entrada es fija y que (por lo que veo) el único resultado que importa es lo que imprime en pantalla el proceso es muy simple por que no tienes que preocuparte por los valores de retorno, solo por encerrar todo en una función.

Vamos a hacer el ejemplo con un bloque de código cualquiera:

```
foo = 1
bar = foo + 2
pass
print(foo + bar)
```

Si queremos ponerlo en una función llamada *hacer_cosas*, el código quedaría así:

```
def hacer_cosas():
    foo = 1
    bar = foo + 2
    pass
    print(foo + bar)
```

Y listo, ahora puedes llamar a tu función usando:

```
hacer_cosas()
```

No obstante, tu código contiene algo que valdría la pena que cambiara en cada ocasión. Concretamente el arreglo junio posteriormente podría tornarse en diferentes arreglos con datos distintos meses. Entonces ahora nos hace falta añadir argumentos de función al código.

Antes de hacerlo, vamos a hacer un ejemplo con un código más sencillo:

```
nombre_raul = "Raul Armando Hoyos"
print("Hola", nombre_raul)
```

Queremos generalizarlo un poco de manera que no solo salude a Raul, por lo que deberíamos cambiar el nombre de la variable para que sea más general. "nombre" o "nombre_persona" serían nombres más adecuados. Además cuando pasemos este código a una función no debemos asignar el valor a esa variable nosotros mismos, sino que debemos indicar que es un valor que se recibe de fuera. La forma de especificar eso es algo así:

```
def saludar_persona(nombre_persona):
    print("Hola", nombre_persona)
```

Es muy importante notar que aún no sabemos cual será el nombre de la persona. Eso se le dirá cuando llamemos la función. Por ejemplo, podremos hacer:

```
saludar_persona("Juan Rivera")
saludar_persona("Esmeralda Sanchez")
persona3 = "Raul Armando Hoyos"
saludar_persona(persona3) # Sin comillas
```

Todos los nombres que pasamos serán asignados a la variable *nombre_persona* dentro de la función y el código saludará con el nombre correspondiente.

En tú caso como ya dije, conviene hacer que en lugar de siempre usar *junio*, se pueda pasar un *mes* cualquiera como argumento a la función. El resto del código se quedaría básicamente igual:

```
def mostrar_consumo_megas(mes):
    aplicaciones = []
    consumo_total = []

    for app in mes:
        nombre_app = app[0 : app.index('-')]
        consumo_app = int(app[app.index('-') + 1 : i.index('M')])
        if not nombre_app in aplicaciones:
            aplicaciones.append(nombre_app)
            consumo_total.append(consumo_app)
        else:
            indice = aplicaciones.index(nombre_app)
            consumo_total[indice] += consumo_app

    for indice_nuevo in range(len(aplicaciones)):
        print(aplicaciones[indice_nuevo], '-', 'Megas', consumo_total[indice_nuevo])
```

Para obtener el mismo resultado, bastaría con pasar a la función el arreglo junio que ya existe en el programa:

```
mostrar_consumo_megas(junio)
```